# how to run springboot test without run tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am developing a spring boot application and write some junit test.

But I find when I run any tests, tomcat is also started up, It makes those tests very slow and waste many times.

When I develop a SpringMvc application, junit test can run without start tomcat, It saves many times.

So, I want to ask it there anyway to run springboot test with out start tomcat?

Comment: Can you post the logs where you detect that tomcat is getting starts ??

Comment: Can you provide us snippets of your test class? My tests are annotated with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and tomcat is not started when running mvn test

Answer (score 7):

Running a test with @SpringBootTest does not start an embedded server by default.
By default, it runs in the MOCK environment.

> By default, @SpringBootTest will not start a server. You can use the
> webEnvironment attribute of @SpringBootTest to further refine how your
> tests run:
>
> MOCK(Default) : Loads a web ApplicationContext and provides a mock web
> environment. Embedded servers are not started when using this
> annotation. If a web environment is not available on your classpath,
> this mode transparently falls back to creating a regular non-web
> ApplicationContext. It can be used in conjunction with
> @AutoConfigureMockMvc or @AutoConfigureWebTestClient for mock-based
> testing of your web application.

Documentation link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

I guess what you wanted to achieve could be achieved by **Slice Test** concept. In general, you don't need a *full-fledged mock environment* or *environment with an embedded server* with all the configured beans in the spring container when you are performing unit tests.

For e.g. you have to unit test your **Controller** then you have **@WebMvcTest** annotation in place that will configure only web related beans and ignore the rest of the beans.

> To test whether Spring MVC controllers are working as expected, use
> the @WebMvcTest annotation. @WebMvcTest auto-configures the Spring MVC
> infrastructure and limits scanned beans to @Controller,
> @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter, GenericConverter,
> Filter, WebMvcConfigurer, and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. Regular
> @Component beans are not scanned when using this annotation.

Documentation link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests

Similarly, for the database layer, there is **@DataJpaTest**

Documentation link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test

Long story short: when you intend to do unit testing with Spring framework, **slice test** is the one *you should use in most of the cases*.

Comment: Did you mean to write "does NOT start" in your first sentence?

Answer (score -2):

If you are placing the following annotations, this will start the embedded container...

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Because, if you see the `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class` class , this has been invoked the container which is invoked by `@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)` when we specify  `@SpringBootTest`

You can remove those and can do as follows:

```
import org.junit.Test;    
public class HellotomApplicationTests {    
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

R-Click and RunAs Junit

O/P
[image]